# How to check between range of values of same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, union

This is the table I have:

[image]

Now, I want to check if the input is between 95-91 or 80-90 or 70-79...and so on.

How can I do that ?

Comment: You don't want to use `BETWEEN` - what happens when somebody records a grade of `79.5`?  Use an exclusive upper-bound (`<`) instead.  I prefer constructing the necessary view on-the-fly, but have limited typing capabilities at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we join the table to itself to get the min and max values for each grade.

```
select
    g1.Courseid,
    g1.GradeValue MinGradeValue,
    isnull(min(g2.GradeValue)-1,100) MaxGradeValue,
    g1.Description
from YourTable g1
    left join YourTable g2
        ON g2.CourseId = g1.CourseId
        and g2.GradeValue > g1.GradeValue
group by
    g1.Courseid,
    g1.GradeValue,
    g1.Description
```

You can join this as a CTE or something to a Student's grade with `Student.Grade between MinGradeValue and MaxGradeValue`. Let me know if I can help you further.

Comment: I'm getting an error on:

Column 'Temp.Description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You are quite welcome. Happy to help! If this was helpful, please consider selecting it as the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, stop thinking in inclusive upper-bound ranges; read [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) about `BETWEEN` (which is an inclusive range) - this applies to anything that is conceptually **not** an integral count (ie, pretty much everything).  What happens when somebody gets a grade of `79.5`?

Fortunately, your table is perfectly setup for constructing a bounding-range table (which can be done as a CTE here, or as a materialized view if strictly necessary).  I tend to prefer OLAP functions for this sort of work (and 2012 has a nice one for this):

```
SELECT courseId, description, 
       gradeValue as minimumValue, 
       LEAD(gradeValue) OVER(PARTITION BY courseId ORDER BY gradeValue) as nextGradeMinimumValue
FROM Grade
```

... Which you can then query against similar to this:

```
SELECT StudentGrade.studentId, StudentGrade.courseId, StudentGrade.grade,
       Grade.description
FROM (VALUES(1, 1, 38),
            (2, 1, 99),
            (3, 2, 74.5),
            (4, 2, 120)) StudentGrade(studentId, courseId, grade)
JOIN (SELECT courseId, description, 
             gradeValue as minimumValue, 
             LEAD(gradeValue) OVER(PARTITION BY courseId ORDER BY gradeValue) as nextGradeMinimumValue
      FROM Grade) Grade
ON Grade.courseId = StudentGrade.courseId
   AND Grade.minimumValue >= StudentGrade.grade
   AND (Grade.nextGradeMinimumValue IS NULL OR Grade.nextGradeMinimumValue > StudentGrade.grade)
```

(ordinarily I'd have an SQL Fiddle example, but I can't access it at the moment, so this is untested).
This should work for all (positive) grade ranges, including an unlimited amount of "extra credit" (any score higher than the top boundary is assigned that description).